# Does sexual arousal really release testerone?

Tags: strength, sleep, muscle-gain, testosterone, sex

So I have been told that the more sexual stimulation created by a male, the more testosterone his body produces. Is this true?

Comment: This seems like something that belongs on skeptics exchange.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, testosterone is produced more when you have sexual stimulation. This is because testosterone is produced in the testicles, which are responsible for sexual reproduction. When a male is aroused, his testosterone levels will spike up, due to the fact that it stimulates the chemicals moving around in the guy's testicles. In a 2012 study, it was discovered by British researchers that levels of testerone increased in almost forty percent of men after visiting a sex club. http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2239621/Researchers-test-mens-testosterone-levels-rise-arousal--visiting-sex-club.html